# Bootstrap divs not stacking right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two divs with `.container` class which are not stacking properly. Instead, they overlap.

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="crossfadingImages" class="container">
    <img src="./media/..." class="bottom img-responsive" alt="..."/> 
    <img src="./media/..." class="top img-responsive" alt="..."/>
</div>

<div id="about" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p>about...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#crossfadingImages{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 55px;
}
#crossfadingImages img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
     transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
}
#crossfadingImages img.top:hover{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

I think the problem is absolute position of images in crossfadingImages div.
Please provide your solution to my problem as well as an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you can you the `hover()` function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#crossfadingImages img').hover(function() {
      $('#crossfadingImages img:first-child').stop().fadeOut(500);
      $('#crossfadingImages img:last-child').stop().fadeIn(500);
    },
    function() {
      $('#crossfadingImages img:first-child').stop().fadeIn(500);
      $('#crossfadingImages img:last-child').stop().fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

```css
#crossfadingImages {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 55px;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
}
#crossfadingImages img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 45%;
  left: 0;
}
#crossfadingImages img:last-child {
  display: none;
}
#about{
  position:relative;
  top:80px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="crossfadingImages" class="container">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="bottom img-responsive" alt="..." />
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Logo_2013_Google.png" class="top img-responsive" alt="..." />
</div>

<div id="about" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <p>about...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, I think you didn't get what I'm looking for. I have two dofferent images, one below another. When you hover over first image another appears with transition.

Comment: When I unhover, the first image does not appear again. Update this and I will accept your answer. But is there any other way, by using just CSS?

Comment: Updated... I don't think it can be done by css alone

Comment: Just one more thing. Why about text does not appear below the images?

Comment: Because of `position:absolute` in `#crossfadingImages`

Comment: Can you please check my answer below and say what do you think of it? However its only applicable under condition written in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to solve this problem by using only CSS.

**NOTE:** This will only work if you have two images (JPG or JPEG format) of the same size. If they aren't the same size then the bottom image will be shown all the time cause we are just changing opacity of top image.

```css
#crossfadingImages{
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin-top: 55px;
}
#crossfadingImages img{
 left: 0;
        width: 45%;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
 transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
}
#crossfadingImages img.top:hover{
 opacity: 0;
}
.bottom-image{
 position: absolute;
}
.top-image{
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="crossfadingImages" class="container">
 <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="bottom img-responsive bottom-image" alt="..."/> 
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Logo_2013_Google.png" class="top img-responsive top-image" alt="..."/>
</div>
    
<div id="about" class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <p>about...</p>
  </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
    
         </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool Man... Its also nice... But IMHO, The good programmer shouldn't say "use this resource, then only you will get the output". Is it ok with your requirement? If so, this should be the solution.